# change color of a row without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am working on a project at the moment. In iI am using ajax to update and calculate scores, which works fine. However, I have a color scheme that changes according to the score. The color does change, but only after the page is refreshed. Is there anyway I can get the color to change with refreshing the page? In my previous versions I used a button to refresh the page, but is there any way I can accomplish this without refreshing the page?

Here is the code that I am using to assign colors:

```
<?php $row_class = "";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbResult1))
    {
          if($row['total_mai'] <= 2)
             $row_class = "success";
          else if($row['total_mai'] >= 5)
               $row_class = "danger";
          else if($row['total_mai'] >= 3 and $row['total_mai'] < 5)
               $row_class = "warning";

          // echo $row_class;
    ?>
```

In another page, here is an example of one question, it has three answers and depending on the answer a color is assigned based on the score

```
<tr>
   <td class="form-group col-md-6">Is the duration of therapy acceptable?</td>
   <td class="form-group col-md-6">
       <p class="radio-inline">
       <input type="radio" name="therapydur" id="j1" value="0" <?php echo $j1; ?> required onchange="ajaxFunction('therapydur','<?php echo $count; ?>','0','<?php echo $row['p_id']; ?>')">
       <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="acceptable">A</a>
       </input></p>

       <p class="radio-inline">
       <input type="radio" name="therapydur" id="j2" value="0" <?php echo $j2; ?> required onchange="ajaxFunction('therapydur','<?php echo $count; ?>','0','<?php echo $row['p_id']; ?>')">
       <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="marginally acceptable">B</a>
       </input></p>

       <p class="radio-inline">
       <input type="radio" name="therapydur" id="j3" value="1" <?php echo $j3; ?> required onchange="ajaxFunction('therapydur','<?php echo $count; ?>','1','<?php echo $row['p_id']; ?>')">
       <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="unacceptable">C</a>
       </input></p>
   </td>
   </tr>

Here is the ajax from the same page:

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


    function ajaxFunction(title,id,val,p_id)
    {
             //alert("test");
             //alert(id);
             //alert(val);
             //alert(title);
             //alert(p_id);
             var xmlhttp;
             if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
             {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
             }
             else
             {// code for IE6, IE5
                 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }
             xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
             {
                   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                   {
                      //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                      var resp = xmlhttp.responseText;
                      var split_v = resp.split("__");
                      //alert(split_v.length);
                      //alert(split_v[1]);
                      document.getElementById("ajaxDiv_"+id).innerHTML=split_v[0];
                      document.getElementById("ajaxTotal").innerHTML=split_v[1];

                   }
             }

             xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_mai.php?pdr_id="+id+"&value="+val+"&title="+title+"&p_id="+p_id,true);
             xmlhttp.send();
             return true;
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: You'll want to use css set on the element via js to change the colours

Comment: ok, does it make any difference if I am using bootstrap? Would you have an samples I could look at?

Comment: Are you setting colours via classes? If so list them. Are you returning just html in the ajax request or json?

Comment: No, the colors are being set according to a score e.g. if total > 5 ="success"

Comment: can you show the data that is returned from your ajax call? Is it json? Does the $row_class get returned in the response?

Comment: basically the data is returned is a score from 10 question, as in the example above.

Comment: @BarryMcDaid1982 I think you misunderstand. What is returned via the ajax request? Is it html/json/some other format?

Answer (score 0):

you need to load script to ajax as well as you load dom via ajax because script in yoyr static page can not run to your ajax data

Comment: how exactly would I do that? I have only started using ajax last week, so this is pretty new to me, thanks

Comment: you can load a seprate script file with your data that you get from ajax like echo this or reurn it

Comment: could you give an example or adapt my code to show me please?